# Access remote database using DataSnap technology in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, c++builder, datasnap

How to query and get results from remote database using DataSnap  technology in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin ?

I want to build a simple solution having two  VCL Forms Applications, like client(1) and server(2), running on two different windows os computers, connected on same local network.

But I cannot accomplish this simple task and this is what I tried to do:

On the server application (2), I use:

```
TSQLConnection *SQLConnection1;
TSQLQuery *SQLQuery1;
```

and I will load a SQLite database version 3:

```
 if (SQLConnection1->Params->IndexOf("Database") == -1)
     {
        SQLConnection1->Params->Add("Database="+Form->DataBaseFile );
     }
     else
     {
        SQLConnection1->Params->Values["Database"] = Form->DataBaseFile;
     }

     try
     {
        SQLConnection1->Connected = true;
     }
     catch (EDatabaseError& E)
     {
       ShowMessage("Exception raised with message" + E.Message);
     }
```

and execute sql query:

```
 try
 {
   SQLQuery1->SQL->Text = "query from client app(1)";
   SQLQuery1->Active = false;
   SQLQuery1->ExecSQL();


 }
 catch (Exception& E)
 {
    ShowMessage( "SQLite exception raised with message:\n\n" + E.Message);
    SQLConnection1->Connected = false;
 }
```

and I need to return SQLQuery1 results back to client app(1)

On the client application I think I should do something like below, but I'm not sure, I don't know how to do this correctly:

```
TSQLServerMethod *SQLServerMethod1;

SQLServerMethod->SQLConnection = SQLConnection1;

   try{
     SQLServerMethod.ServerMethodName = "TDSUtilityMethods.echoOutStr";
     SQLServerMethod->Params[0]->AsString = "123";
     SQLServerMethod->ExecuteMethod();
     memoOutput->Text = SQLServerMethod->Params[1]->AsString;
  }
   finally{
     SQLServerMethod->Close();
   }
```

So the purpose is to make a server application(2) which host and execute sql queries from client app(1) which sends the sql query and waits for results. The application(1) which send sql query is a wrapper of chromium client. I tried to achieve all this solution using  TIdHTTPServer on sever app(2) and WebSockets from chromium client app(1), and posted a releated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438988/websocket-connect-to-tidhttpserver-handshake-issue) but implementing WebSocket protocol(encoding/decoding packets) is a bit hard for an amateur developer. And then I found that a easier solution could be using DataSnap technology. I have read about [Developing DataSnap Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Developing_DataSnap_Applications), but still not able to build this simple solution, on embarcadero website are described each component, but because I'm amateur developer, I found it confusing and hard to complete a simple task which seems possible and easier to build using DataSnap technology than WebSockets. But now I found hard to implement DataSnap technology, because there is a lot of new things which are confusing without examples.

Please if you know how to do this in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin, show here a short sample of that.

Comment: Firstly you realise that `query from client app(1)` is not a valid Sql query that your SqlQuery1 could execute?  Secondly, there are C++ examples of using DataSnap here: https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Tokyo/CPP/DataSnap/

Comment: I know, but that example is useless

Comment: Then try the Delphi examples - they all work fine and are not useless.

Comment: You'll be facing a risk of executing any query. But let's overlook that for now. Can you use FireDAC? It can easily (de)serialize datasets. Otherwise you'll need to (de)serialize dataset by yourself.

Comment: @Victoria The risk is fine as long as this app runs in local private network. About FireDAC I don't know about it, I'm amateur developer and I do not know many things, but I want to build a VCL app for Windows, and I use  C++ Builder for that because it seems rapid app development solution.

Comment: It's a set of components shipped with EMBT products that can make this task easy. Depends on which SKU you have (I'm afraid that Enterprise+ is needed to have a remote connection accessed). The point is that you need to somehow transfer the dataset. Client side sends the query, server side fetches dataset and that dataset serializes in some way and sends to the client (usually as JSON, XML, or more efficient formats). And client side as it understands that format can deserialize the response back into a dataset with which you can then comfortably.

Comment: @Victoria Yes I have FireDAC. JSON is fine for dataset. I use it in javascript development. But I already have my application created and I just want to add an option to query and save data on remote database which is managed by a server app on other PC connected in same local network. I just want to see an example how to do that using DataSnap technology or whatever technology which is available in C++ Builder, because I use VCL Forms application, I hope 
that I need to drop some DataSnap components on my form and  not need to create new project. I hope you can show me a client and server

Comment: In case you help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXEuZNc60Hw

Comment: How to (de)serialize FireDAC dataset is shown e.g. in [this tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_REST_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application_and_FireDAC).