# convert TDataSet results to JSON format

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Need to achieve a common conversion between TDataset and JSON in C++ Builder, for the realization of data communication and conversion. However, this is difficult for an amateur developer.

I've found this already done in Delphi, but I don't know Delphi, however it seems to be good example. Maybe somebody can convert it to C++ Builder:

```
unit uDBJson;

interface
uses
SysUtils,Classes,Variants,DB,DBClient,SuperObject;

type
TTableJSon = class

private
    const cstFieldType = 'FieldType';
    const cstFieldName = 'FieldName';
    const cstFieldSize = 'FieldSize';
    const cstJsonType = 'JsonType';
    const cstRequired = 'Required';
    const cstFieldIndex = 'FieldIndex';

    const cstCols= 'Cols';
    const cstData= 'Data';

public
    class function JSonFromDataSet(DataSet:TDataSet):string;
    class function CreateFieldByJson(Fields:TFieldDefs;ColsJson:ISuperObject):Boolean;
    class function ImportDataFromJSon(DataSet:TDataSet;DataJson:ISuperObject):Integer;
    class function CDSFromJSon(CDS:TClientDataSet;Json:ISuperObject):Boolean;
    class function GetValue(Json:ISuperObject;const Name:string):Variant;

    class function CreateJsonValue(Json:ISuperObject;const Name:string;const Value:Variant):Boolean;
    class function CreateJsonValueByField(Json:ISuperObject;Field:TField):Boolean;
    class function GetValue2Field(Field:TField;JsonValue:ISuperObject):Variant;
end;
implementation
uses TypInfo,encddecd;

{ TTableJSon }

class function TTableJSon.CDSFromJSon(CDS: TClientDataSet;
Json: ISuperObject): Boolean;
var
ColsJson:ISuperObject;
begin
Result := False;
if Json = nil then
    Exit;
CDS.Close;
CDS.Data := Null;

ColsJson := Json.O[cstCols];
CreateFieldByJson(CDS.FieldDefs,ColsJson);
if CDS.FieldDefs.Count >0 then
    CDS.CreateDataSet;
ImportDataFromJSon(CDS,Json.O[cstData]);
Result := True;
end;

class function TTableJSon.CreateFieldByJson(Fields: TFieldDefs;
ColsJson: ISuperObject): Boolean;
var
SubJson:ISuperObject;
ft:TFieldType;
begin
Result := False;
Fields.DataSet.Close;
Fields.Clear;
for SubJson in ColsJson do
begin
    ft := TFieldType(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TFieldType),'ft'+SubJson.S[cstFieldType]));
    if ft= ftAutoInc then 
      ft := ftInteger;
    Fields.Add(SubJson.S[cstFieldName],ft,SubJson.I[cstFieldSize],SubJson.B[cstRequired]);
end;
Result := True;
end;

class function TTableJSon.CreateJsonValue(Json: ISuperObject;
const Name: string; const Value: Variant): Boolean;
begin
Result := False;
Json.O[Name] := SO(Value);
Result := True;
end;

class function TTableJSon.CreateJsonValueByField(Json: ISuperObject;
Field: TField): Boolean;
begin
Result := False;
if Field Is TDateTimeField then
    Json.O[Field.FieldName] := SO(Field.AsDateTime)
else if Field is TBlobField then
    Json.S[Field.FieldName] := EncodeString(Field.AsString)
else
    Json.O[Field.FieldName] := SO(Field.Value);
Result := True;
end;

class function TTableJSon.GetValue(
Json: ISuperObject;const Name: string): Variant;
begin
case Json.DataType of
    stNull: Result := Null;
    stBoolean: Result := Json.B[Name];
    stDouble: Result := Json.D[Name];
    stCurrency: Result := Json.C[Name];
    stInt: Result := Json.I[Name];
    stString: Result := Json.S[Name];
end;
end;

class function TTableJSon.GetValue2Field(Field: TField; JsonValue:ISuperObject): Variant;
begin
if JsonValue.DataType = stNull then
    Result := Null
else if Field is TDateTimeField then
    Result := JavaToDelphiDateTime(JsonValue.AsInteger)
else if (Field is TIntegerField) or (Field is TLargeintField) then
    Result := JsonValue.AsInteger
else if Field is TNumericField then
    Result := JsonValue.AsDouble
else if Field is TBooleanField then
    Result := JsonValue.AsBoolean
else if Field is TStringField then
    Result := JsonValue.AsString
else if Field is TBlobField then
    Result := DecodeString(JsonValue.AsString)    

end;

class function TTableJSon.ImportDataFromJSon(DataSet: TDataSet;
DataJson: ISuperObject): Integer;
var
SubJson:ISuperObject;
i:Integer;
iter: TSuperObjectIter;
begin
if not DataSet.Active then
    DataSet.Open;
DataSet.DisableControls;
try
    for SubJson in DataJson do
    begin
      DataSet.Append;
      if ObjectFindFirst(SubJson,iter) then
      begin
         repeat
           if DataSet.FindField(iter.Ite.Current.Name)<>nil then
             DataSet.FindField(iter.Ite.Current.Name).Value :=
                GetValue2Field(
                DataSet.FindField(iter.Ite.Current.Name),
                iter.Ite.Current.Value);
         until not ObjectFindNext(iter) ;
      end;
      DataSet.Post;
    end;
finally
    DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
end;

class function TTableJSon.JSonFromDataSet(DataSet:TDataSet):string;
procedure GetFieldTypeInfo(Field:TField;var Fieldtyp,JsonTyp:string);
begin
    Fieldtyp := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(tfieldtype),ord(Field.DataType));
    Delete(Fieldtyp,1,2);
    if Field is TStringField then
      JsonTyp := 'string'
    else if Field is TDateTimeField then
      JsonTyp := 'integer'
    else if (Field is TIntegerField) or (Field is TLargeintField) then
      JsonTyp := 'integer'
    else if Field is TCurrencyField then
      JsonTyp := 'currency'
    else if Field is TNumericField then
      JsonTyp := 'double'
    else if Field is TBooleanField then
      JsonTyp := 'boolean'
    else
      JsonTyp := 'variant';
end;
var
sj,aj,sj2:ISuperObject;
i:Integer;
Fieldtyp,JsonTyp:string;
List:TStringList;
begin
sj := SO();

aj := SA([]);
List := TStringList.Create;
try
    List.Sorted := True;

    for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      sj2 := SO();
      GetFieldTypeInfo(DataSet.Fields[i],Fieldtyp,JsonTyp);

      sj2.S[cstFieldName] := DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName;
      sj2.S[cstFieldType] := Fieldtyp;
      sj2.S[cstJsonType] := JsonTyp;
      sj2.I[cstFieldSize] := DataSet.Fields[i].Size;
      sj2.B[cstRequired] := DataSet.Fields[i].Required;
      sj2.I[cstFieldIndex] := DataSet.Fields[i].Index;
      aj.AsArray.Add(sj2);
      List.Add(DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName+'='+JsonTyp);
    end;
    sj.O['Cols'] := aj;

    DataSet.DisableControls;

    DataSet.First;
    aj := SA([]);
    while not DataSet.Eof do
    begin
      sj2 := SO();
      for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
      begin
        //sj2.S[IntToStr(DataSet.Fields[i].Index)] := VarToStrDef(DataSet.Fields[i].Value,'');
        if VarIsNull(DataSet.Fields[i].Value) then
          sj2.O[DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName] := SO(Null)
        else
        begin
          CreateJsonValueByField(sj2,DataSet.Fields[i]);
        end;
      end;
      aj.AsArray.Add(sj2);
      DataSet.Next;
    end;
    sj.O['Data'] := aj;

    Result := sj.AsString;
finally
    List.Free;
    DataSet.EnableControls;
end;

end;

end.





var
json:TTableJSon;
s:string;

begin

S := json.JSonFromDataSet(ADODataSet1);



end;



var
json:ISuperObject;
begin
json := TSuperObject.ParseFile('json.txt',False);
TTableJSon.CDSFromJSon(cdsJSON,json);
end;
```

Here is what I did/got using C++ Builder compiler which translated from pascal to c++, this code:

```
    // CodeGear C++Builder
    // Copyright (c) 1995, 2016 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
    // All rights reserved

    // (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'uDBJson.pas' rev: 31.00 (Windows)

    #ifndef UdbjsonHPP
    #define UdbjsonHPP

    #pragma delphiheader begin
    #pragma option push
    #pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
    #pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member 
    #pragma pack(push,8)
    #include <System.hpp>
    #include <SysInit.hpp>
    #include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
    #include <System.Classes.hpp>
    #include <System.Variants.hpp>
    #include <Data.DB.hpp>
    #include <Datasnap.DBClient.hpp>
    #include "superdate.hpp"
    #include "superobject.hpp"

    //-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

    namespace Udbjson
    {
    //-- forward type declarations -----------------------------------------------
    class DELPHICLASS TTableJSon;
    //-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
    #pragma pack(push,4)
    class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TTableJSon : public System::TObject
    {
        typedef System::TObject inherited;

    private:
        #define cstFieldType L"FieldType"

        #define cstFieldName L"FieldName"

        #define cstFieldSize L"FieldSize"

        #define cstJsonType L"JsonType"

        #define cstRequired L"Required"

        #define cstFieldIndex L"FieldIndex"

        #define cstCols L"Cols"

        #define cstData L"Data"


    public:
        __classmethod System::UnicodeString __fastcall JSonFromDataSet(Data::Db::TDataSet* DataSet);
        __classmethod bool __fastcall CreateFieldByJson(Data::Db::TFieldDefs* Fields, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject ColsJson);
        __classmethod int __fastcall ImportDataFromJSon(Data::Db::TDataSet* DataSet, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject DataJson);
        __classmethod bool __fastcall CDSFromJSon(Datasnap::Dbclient::TClientDataSet* CDS, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json);
        __classmethod System::Variant __fastcall GetValue(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, const System::UnicodeString Name);
        __classmethod bool __fastcall CreateJsonValue(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, const System::UnicodeString Name, const System::Variant &Value);
        __classmethod bool __fastcall CreateJsonValueByField(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, Data::Db::TField* Field);
        __classmethod System::Variant __fastcall GetValue2Field(Data::Db::TField* Field, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject JsonValue);
    public:
        /* TObject.Create */ inline __fastcall TTableJSon(void) : System::TObject() { }
        /* TObject.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TTableJSon(void) { }

    };

    bool __fastcall TTableJSon::CDSFromJSon(Datasnap::Dbclient::TClientDataSet* CDS, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json)
    {
      ISuperObject *ColsJson;
      bool Result = false;

      if(Json == NULL)return Result;

        CDS->Close();
        CDS->Data = NULL;

       ColsJson = Json->O[cstCols];
       CreateFieldByJson(CDS->FieldDefs,ColsJson);
       if(CDS->FieldDefs->Count >0)CDS->CreateDataSet();
        ImportDataFromJSon(CDS,Json->O[cstData]);
       return true;
    }


    bool __fastcall TTableJSon::CreateFieldByJson(Data::Db::TFieldDefs* Fields, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject ColsJson)
    {

      ISuperObject *SubJson;
      TFieldType *ft;
      bool Result = false;

      Fields->DataSet->Close();
      Fields->Clear();

      // Delphi Pascal code, which I don't know how to convert     
      for SubJson in ColsJson do
begin
    ft := TFieldType(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TFieldType),'ft'+SubJson.S[cstFieldType]));
    if ft= ftAutoInc then 
      ft := ftInteger;
    Fields.Add(SubJson.S[cstFieldName],ft,SubJson.I[cstFieldSize],SubJson.B[cstRequired]);
end;
      return true;

    }

    #pragma pack(pop)

    //-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
    }   /* namespace Udbjson */
    #if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_UDBJSON)
    using namespace Udbjson;
    #endif
    #pragma pack(pop)
    #pragma option pop

    #pragma delphiheader end.
    //-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
    #endif  // UdbjsonHPP
```

Please help to translate this code to C++ Builder.

right now I don't know how to translate this piece of code:

```
for SubJson in ColsJson do
begin
    ft := TFieldType(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TFieldType),'ft'+SubJson.S[cstFieldType]));
    if ft= ftAutoInc then 
      ft := ftInteger;
    Fields.Add(SubJson.S[cstFieldName],ft,SubJson.I[cstFieldSize],SubJson.B[cstRequired]);
end;
```

All other the missing code of superobject can be found here:
https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject

**UPDATE ________________________________________**

Below is what I tried to translated from Delphi to C++ Builder, and the only errors I got when tried to compile I have pasted below. Please check this and help to make it correctly translated.

```
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2016 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'uDBJson.pas' rev: 31.00 (Windows)

#ifndef UdbjsonHPP
#define UdbjsonHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member 
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>
#include <SysInit.hpp>
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <System.Variants.hpp>
#include <Data.DB.hpp>
#include <Datasnap.DBClient.hpp>
#include "superdate.hpp"
#include "superobject.hpp"

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Udbjson
{
//-- forward type declarations -----------------------------------------------
class DELPHICLASS TTableJSon;
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
#pragma pack(push,4)
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TTableJSon : public System::TObject
{
    typedef System::TObject inherited;

private:
    #define cstFieldType L"FieldType"

    #define cstFieldName L"FieldName"

    #define cstFieldSize L"FieldSize"

    #define cstJsonType L"JsonType"

    #define cstRequired L"Required"

    #define cstFieldIndex L"FieldIndex"

    #define cstCols L"Cols"

    #define cstData L"Data"


public:
    __classmethod System::UnicodeString __fastcall JSonFromDataSet(Data::Db::TDataSet* DataSet);
    __classmethod bool __fastcall CreateFieldByJson(Data::Db::TFieldDefs* Fields, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject ColsJson);
    __classmethod int __fastcall ImportDataFromJSon(Data::Db::TDataSet* DataSet, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject DataJson);
    __classmethod bool __fastcall CDSFromJSon(Datasnap::Dbclient::TClientDataSet* CDS, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json);
    __classmethod System::Variant __fastcall GetValue(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, const System::UnicodeString Name);
    __classmethod bool __fastcall CreateJsonValue(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, const System::UnicodeString Name, const System::Variant &Value);
    __classmethod bool __fastcall CreateJsonValueByField(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, Data::Db::TField* Field);
    __classmethod System::Variant __fastcall GetValue2Field(Data::Db::TField* Field, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject JsonValue);
public:
    /* TObject.Create */ inline __fastcall TTableJSon(void) : System::TObject() { }
    /* TObject.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TTableJSon(void) { }

};



#pragma pack(pop)

bool __fastcall TTableJSon::CDSFromJSon(Datasnap::Dbclient::TClientDataSet* CDS, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json)
{
  ISuperObject *ColsJson;
  bool Result = false;

  if(Json == NULL)return Result;

    CDS->Close();
    CDS->Data = NULL;

   ColsJson = Json->O[cstCols];
   CreateFieldByJson(CDS->FieldDefs,ColsJson);
   if(CDS->FieldDefs->Count >0)CDS->CreateDataSet();
    ImportDataFromJSon(CDS,Json->O[cstData]);
   return true;
}


bool __fastcall TTableJSon::CreateFieldByJson(Data::Db::TFieldDefs* Fields, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject ColsJson)
{

  ISuperObject *SubJson;
  TFieldType ft;
  bool Result = false;

  Fields->DataSet->Close();
  Fields->Clear();


  for(int i = 0; i < ColsJson->AsArray()->Length; ++i)
  {
    SubJson = ColsJson->AsArray()->O[i]; //>GetO(i);

    ft = TFieldType(GetEnumValue(__delphirtti(TFieldType), "ft" + SubJson->S[cstFieldType]));

    if(ft == ftAutoInc)
      ft = ftInteger;

    Fields->Add(SubJson->S[cstFieldName], ft, SubJson->I[cstFieldSize], SubJson->B[cstRequired]);
  }

  return true;
}

bool __fastcall TTableJSon::CreateJsonValue(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, const System::UnicodeString Name, const System::Variant &Value)
{
  bool Result = false;

  Json->O[Name] = SO(Value);

  return true;
}


bool __fastcall TTableJSon::CreateJsonValueByField(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, Data::Db::TField* Field)
{
  bool Result = false;

  if(dynamic_cast<TDateTimeField*>(Field) != 0)
    Json->O[Field->FieldName] = SO(Field->AsDateTime);
  else if(dynamic_cast<TBlobField*>(Field) != 0)
    Json->S[Field->FieldName] = Field->AsString; //EncodeString(..) Field->AsVariant;  TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(m1.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);  TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(myString);
  else
    Json->O[Field->FieldName] = SO(Field->Value);

    return true;
}


System::Variant __fastcall TTableJSon::GetValue(Superobject::_di_ISuperObject Json, const System::UnicodeString Name)
{
 switch(Json->DataType)
 {
    case stNull: return NULL; break;
    case stBoolean: return Json->B[Name]; break;
    case stDouble: return  Json->D[Name];  break;
    case stCurrency: return  Json->C[Name]; break;
    case stInt: return Json->I[Name]; break;
    case stString: return  Json->S[Name]; break;
 }
 return NULL;
}

System::Variant __fastcall TTableJSon::GetValue2Field(Data::Db::TField* Field, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject JsonValue)
{

  if(JsonValue->DataType == stNull)
    return NULL;
   else if(dynamic_cast<TDateTimeField*>(Field) != 0)
        return JavaToDelphiDateTime(JsonValue->AsInteger());
   else if (dynamic_cast<TIntegerField*>(Field) != 0 || dynamic_cast<TLargeintField*>(Field) != 0)
        return JsonValue->AsInteger();
   else if(dynamic_cast<TNumericField*>(Field) != 0)
        return JsonValue->AsDouble();
   else if(dynamic_cast<TBooleanField*>(Field) != 0)
        return JsonValue->AsBoolean();
   else if(dynamic_cast<TStringField*>(Field) != 0)
        return JsonValue->AsString();
   else if(dynamic_cast<TBlobField*>(Field) != 0)
        return JsonValue->AsString(); //DecodeString(JsonValue.AsString)  //Field->AsVariant;  TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(m1.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);  TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(myString);

}

int __fastcall TTableJSon::ImportDataFromJSon(Data::Db::TDataSet* DataSet, Superobject::_di_ISuperObject DataJson)
{
  ISuperObject *SubJson;
  int i;
  TSuperObjectIter iter;

  if(! DataSet->Active)
    DataSet->Open();

   DataSet->DisableControls();

   try
   {

    for(int i = 0; i < DataJson->AsArray()->Length; ++i)
    {
      SubJson = DataJson->AsArray()->O[i]; //>GetO(i);
      DataSet->Append();
      if(ObjectFindFirst(SubJson,iter))
      {
         do
         {  if(DataSet->FindField(iter.Ite->Current->Name) != NULL)
             DataSet->FindField(iter.Ite->Current->Name)->Value =
                GetValue2Field(
                DataSet->FindField(iter.Ite->Current->Name),
                iter.Ite->Current->Value);
         }
         while( ! ObjectFindNext(iter));
      }
      DataSet->Post();
    }
   }
   __finally
   {
    DataSet->EnableControls();
   }
}

void GetFieldTypeInfo(Data::Db::TField *Field, String &Fieldtyp, String &JsonTyp)
{
    Fieldtyp = GetEnumName(__delphirtti(TFieldType),(int)(Field->DataType));
    Fieldtyp = Fieldtyp.Delete(1,2);
    if(dynamic_cast<TStringField*>(Field) != 0)
      JsonTyp = "string";
    else if(dynamic_cast<TDateTimeField*>(Field) != 0)
      JsonTyp = "integer";
    else if(dynamic_cast<TIntegerField*>(Field) != 0 || dynamic_cast<TLargeintField*>(Field) != 0)
      JsonTyp = "integer";
    else if(dynamic_cast<TCurrencyField*>(Field) != 0)
      JsonTyp = "currency";
    else if(dynamic_cast<TNumericField*>(Field) != 0)
      JsonTyp = "double";
    else if(dynamic_cast<TBooleanField*>(Field) != 0)
      JsonTyp = "boolean";
    else
      JsonTyp = "variant";
}


System::UnicodeString __fastcall TTableJSon::JSonFromDataSet(Data::Db::TDataSet* DataSet)
{

 ISuperObject *sj, *aj, *sj2;
 int i;
 String Fieldtyp,JsonTyp;
 TStringList *List;


 sj = SO();
 aj = SA(new TVarRec(),0);
 List = new TStringList;

 try
 {
    List->Sorted = true;

    for(int i = 0; i< DataSet->FieldCount - 1; i++)
    {
      sj2 = SO();
      GetFieldTypeInfo(DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0],Fieldtyp,JsonTyp);

      sj2->S[cstFieldName] = DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->FieldName;
      sj2->S[cstFieldType] = Fieldtyp;
      sj2->S[cstJsonType]  = JsonTyp;
      sj2->I[cstFieldSize] = DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->Size;
      sj2->B[cstRequired]  = DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->Required;
      sj2->I[cstFieldIndex] = DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->Index;
      aj->AsArray()->Add(sj2);
      List->Add(DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->FieldName+"="+JsonTyp);
    }
    sj->O["Cols"] = aj;

    DataSet->DisableControls();

    DataSet->First();
    aj = SA(new TVarRec(),0);
    while(! DataSet->Eof)
    {
      sj2 = SO();
      for(int i = 0; i< DataSet->FieldCount - 1; i++)
      {
        //sj2.S[IntToStr(DataSet.Fields[i].Index)] := VarToStrDef(DataSet.Fields[i].Value,'');
        if(VarIsNull(DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->Value))
          sj2->O[DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]->FieldName] = SO(NULL);
        else
          CreateJsonValueByField(sj2,DataSet->Fields[i].Fields[0]);
      }
      aj->AsArray()->Add(sj2);
      DataSet->Next();
    }

    sj->O["Data"] = aj;

    return sj-> AsString();
 }
 __finally
   {
    List->Free();
    DataSet->EnableControls();
   }



}

//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
}   /* namespace Udbjson */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_UDBJSON)
using namespace Udbjson;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop



#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // UdbjsonHPP

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Udbjson::TTableJSon::' referenced from C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Superobject::SA(System::TVarRec *, const int)' referenced from C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Superobject::SO(System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Superobject::SO(System::Variant&)' referenced from C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Superobject::TSuperArray::Add(bool)' referenced from C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

Comment: Why don't you want to give that `TFDJSONDataSetsReader(Writer)` try?

Comment: @Victoria Ok, but how it will look in C++ Builder

Comment: You can find it in the [linked tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571004/access-remote-database-using-datasnap-technology-in-c-builder-10-1-berlin#comment76466888_44571004) (C++ Builder code included).

Comment: @Victoria Please help me to translate this code from Delphi to C++ Builder:
for SubJson in ColsJson do
begin
    ft := TFieldType(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TFieldType),'ft'+SubJson.S[cstFieldType]));
    if ft= ftAutoInc then 
      ft := ftInteger;
    Fields.Add(SubJson.S[cstFieldName],ft,SubJson.I[cstFieldSize],SubJson.B[cstRequired]);
end;

Answer (score 0):

Actually you will not need to translate pascal code to C++, if you are using RAD Studio, as you can simply just #include "uDBJson.hpp" after you add the uDBJson.pas file directly to your project. Your RAD Studio will create the hpp file for you and you can call the methods in the class